# MSSQL: How to check whether to call sysmail_add_account_sp or not?

Tags: sql-server, email

I have a fragment of the MS-SQL installation script that adds sysmail account (and then sysmail profile...)

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
    @account_name = 'myaccount',
    @description = 'xxx',
    @email_address = 'myaddress@example.com',
    @replyto_address = 'myaddress@example.com',
    @display_name = 'My Mailer Account',
    @mailserver_name = 'smtp.example.com' ;
```

How can I check inside the SQL script whether the account already exists (to skip the duplicit installation that would cause errors)?

Should I query the `msdb.dbo.sysmail_account` view? Or should I rather `TRY ... CATCH` the `EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_account_sp @account_name='myaccount'` that fails if the account does not exist?

Is there any better way?

Comment: The view option seems good enough, just check against the same name. Might need to consider differences between each configuration.

Comment: @EzLo: Thanks. Actually, it is a table. Anyway, copy your coment as the answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query to check if the account already exists, then update (if needed) or create.

```
DECLARE 
    @AccountName VARCHAR(100) = 'account_name',
    @email_address VARCHAR(100) = 'email_address',
    @display_name VARCHAR(100) = 'display_name',
    @replyto_address VARCHAR(100) = 'replyto_address',  
    @description VARCHAR(100) = 'description',   
    @mailserver_name VARCHAR(100) = 'server_name',   
    @mailserver_type VARCHAR(100) = 'server_type',   
    @port VARCHAR(100) = 587,
    @timeout INT = 30,  
    @username VARCHAR(100) = 'username',  
    @password VARCHAR(100) = 'password',  
    @use_default_credentials BIT = 1,
    @enable_ssl BIT = 0


IF EXISTS (SELECT 'email account already created' FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account AS T WHERE T.name = @AccountName)

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_update_account_sp 
        @account_name = @AccountName,  
        @email_address = @email_address,   
        @display_name = @display_name,   
        @replyto_address = @replyto_address,  
        @description = @description,   
        @mailserver_name = @mailserver_name,   
        @mailserver_type = @mailserver_type,   
        @port = @port,   
        @timeout = @timeout,  
        @username = @username,  
        @password = @password,  
        @use_default_credentials = @use_default_credentials,  
        @enable_ssl = @enable_ssl 

ELSE

    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
        @account_name = @AccountName,  
        @email_address = @email_address,   
        @display_name = @display_name,   
        @replyto_address = @replyto_address,  
        @description = @description,   
        @mailserver_name = @mailserver_name,   
        @mailserver_type = @mailserver_type,   
        @port = @port,
        @username = @username,  
        @password = @password,  
        @use_default_credentials = @use_default_credentials,  
        @enable_ssl = @enable_ssl
```